# Ubuntu 18.04 & Intel HD Graphics 530

Tags: intel-graphics, nomodeset

I have a AiO (HP ProOne 400 G2 20-inch Touch All-in-One PC):
Graphics:
"**Intel HD Graphics 530**".
I install Ubuntu 16.04 and then install "intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.6_amd64.deb" but I have error "Distribution not supported".

**Edit**:
I find problem. I can install Ubuntu just with nomodeset mode. So now I have low resolution. In this case what to do I do? I install **Ubuntu 18.04**.

"About" details:
Graphics llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits).
I also checked "Additional Drivers" which indicated,
No additional drivers are available.
No proprietary drivers are in use.

The output for `sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA` is the following:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
product: HD Graphics 530
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
```

Answer (score 2):

This tool was discontinued

More info [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool)

Please refrain from using a discontinued tool because there won't be any bug fixes provided in case you face an issue

Also as it is mentioned in the post, linux already includes necessary drivers, so you should not face any problems without proprietary ones

Comment: But in display setting I have just resolution 640*480.

Comment: can you go here and try to install all the mentioned packages: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2018q1-intel-graphics-stack-recipe

Comment: Also try to update your system to get all the latest packages and check if this fixes your issue, if not then try the above comment

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are many links ([https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2018q1-intel-graphics-stack-recipe](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2018q1-intel-graphics-stack-recipe)). Which links to download?

Comment: First try to upgrade the system, if that does not work only then move ahead with this. You may have problems installing all of them, Linux Kernel - 4.16
Mesa - 18.0
Libdrm - 2.4.91
Libva - 2.1.0
Vaapi intel-driver - 2.1.0
Cairo - 1.15.10
Intel-gpu-tools - 1.22
Xserver - 1.19.99.901

Comment: I find problem. I can install Ubuntu just with nomodeset mode. So now I have low resolution. in this case what to do I do? I install Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Why did you in first place install ubuntu with nomodeset, did you face issues with a normal installation? Are you facing issues with your graphics driver or something else

Comment: When I boot Ubuntu, it boots to a colorful screen and just change color of screen (red, green, blue).

Complete description of my install:
If I select "UEFI - hp PLDS DVDRW DU8AESH" in boot menu and then "install ubuntu" I see just colorful screen (red, green, blue).
If I select "Legacy - hp PLDS DVDRW DU8AESH" in boot menu and then:
1 - Press "F8"
2 - Press "F6"
3 - Select "nomodeset"
4 - Install Ubuntu.
5 - Every thing is OK but I have not good resolution.

Comment: I do not know real I facing issues with graphics driver or something else.

Comment: Do you have a graphics card?

Comment: Model of my AiO :HP ProOne 400 G2 20-inch Touch All-in-One PC. This model has "Intel HD Graphics 530". The output for sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA is the following:

description: VGA compatible controller
product: HD Graphics 530
vendor: Intel Corporation

Comment: @Neda  Did you ever find a solution to your problem?  I have same model same issue. tx