# Xubuntu 20.04.2 Intel HD 530

Tags: xubuntu, intel

Coders and all,

I have a very similar problem to the one listed in this link below:

[Ubuntu 18.04 & Intel HD Graphics 530](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094151/ubuntu-18-04-intel-hd-graphics-530)

I have about 10 donated HP 400 AIO's. They have the same specs as the above link and lshw displays the same hardware listing.  As the user was able to get Ubuntu to install and boot using nomodest setting in /etc/default/grub.  I was able to install Xubuntu 20.04.2  I additionally set the GLX switches to display 1600X900.  After logging in, and after a few minutes, the desktop locks up.  The pointer works moves but no other input is accepted.  I can successfully perform `cntrl alt f1` and login.  So the whole system is not crippled, but the gui is unusable.  I followed the steps advised in the links above, except to attempt to install the software on the intel web site.  I figured that it is no long current.  Just attempting to verify that and glean from my fellow travelers some more in debth troubleshooting steps I might be able to implement.

Regards in Advance,

Couch_Potato

Edit:

```
[  5628.956] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  5628.957] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  5628.957] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  5628.957] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  5628.957] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  5628.957] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  5628.957] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  5628.957] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  5628.957] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  5628.957] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  5628.957] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  5628.957] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  5628.957]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  5628.957] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  5628.957]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  5628.957] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  5628.957]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  5628.957] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  5628.957]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  5628.957] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  5628.957]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  5628.957] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  5628.957] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  5628.957] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  5628.957] (II) Loader magic: 0x56443d13e020
[  5628.957] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  5628.957]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  5628.957]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[  5628.957]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  5628.957]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  5628.959] (++) using VT number 8

[  5628.959] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  5628.962] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  5628.962] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[  5628.967] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0126:1028:0492 rev 9, Mem @ 0xe1400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  5628.967] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  5628.967] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  5628.968] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  5628.968]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[  5628.968]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  5628.968] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[  5628.968] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[  5628.968] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[  5628.968] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  5628.968] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  5628.968] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  5628.968] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  5628.968]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.20.8
[  5628.968]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  5628.968]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[  5628.968] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  5628.968] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  5628.968] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  5628.968]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
[  5628.968]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  5628.968]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  5628.968] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  5628.968] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  5628.968] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  5628.968]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
[  5628.968]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  5628.968]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  5628.968] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  5628.968] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  5628.968] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  5629.344] (**) modeset(0): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[  5629.344] (II) modeset(0): using default device
[  5629.344] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  5629.344] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  5629.344] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  5629.344] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  5629.344] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  5629.344]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 0.0.2
[  5629.344]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[  5629.345] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  5629.345] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[  5629.345] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[  5629.345] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  5629.345] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[  5629.345] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[  5629.345] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[  5629.349] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  5629.349]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.1
[  5629.349]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  5629.376] (II) modeset(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)
[  5629.376] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[  5629.376] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 has no monitor section
[  5629.377] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[  5629.378] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[  5629.379] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[  5629.380] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-2 has no monitor section
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-3 has no monitor section
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 has no monitor section
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 has no monitor section
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output LVDS-1
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: SEC  Model: 5441  Serial#: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2010  Week: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): 6 bits per channel
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Digital interface is undefined
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 29  vert.: 16
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.610 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.330 greenY: 0.550
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.155 blueY: 0.090   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): clock: 76.6 MHz   Image Size:  293 x 165 mm
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1414  h_sync_end 1446 h_blank_end 1616 h_border: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 773  v_sync_end 778 v_blanking: 790 v_border: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): clock: 48.3 MHz   Image Size:  293 x 165 mm
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1414  h_sync_end 1446 h_blank_end 1528 h_border: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 773  v_sync_end 778 v_blanking: 790 v_border: 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):  XXTNN133AT
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Unknown vendor-specific block 0
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff004ca3415400000000
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   00140104901d10780a4bc59c57548c27
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   17505400000001010101010101010101
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   010101010101eb1d56fa500016303020
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   550025a51000001adc1256a250001630
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   3020550025a51000001a000000fe0058
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   58544e4e8031333341540a2000000000
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0):   00004101940000000001010a20200023
[  5629.382] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS-1
```

The changes I have made:
Installed edge kernel (5.8)
Added ppa://oibaf/graphics-drivers
and updated

```
[https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MBpkfyWvZ7/][1]
```

Can someone provide some feedback.

Tx.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest available?

Comment: I did update the bios, but our images use mbr only even though uefi is enabled.

Comment: You did you make installer? Most tools create an installer that can be booted in either UEFI or CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot mode. You then choose UEFI or BIOS boot  of installer from UEFI menu. Some like Rufus only create an installer that works in one mode or the other. So choice on creating installer will determine the only available boot mode.

Comment: Ah sorry, We use clonezilla image created from a single PC created in legacy mode and image from that.

Comment: So it works ok on one system, but not others?  Even though specs may be identical, vendors often change internals. May have different vendors for various features and then you need different drivers.

Comment: Yeah it generally works off the magnetic media.  lsmod show the i915 module loaded.  The performance is unacceptable.  Is there another grub parameter that will help with troubleshooting?  I am still perusing logs looking for when the flashing starts on the screen.

Comment: Does top or install htop show anything useful. Open it immediately while system is running to see if CPU, RAM or drive is overloaded.

Comment: It never gets to the point where I can access a command line.

Comment: Do not understand, you say it works in one comment & in other say you cannot get to command line?

Comment: Sorry @oldfred,  There has been one way to get it to boot, be usable and that is using nomodeset in /etc/default/grub or from the grub boot edit.  Otherwise if I just leave it with the original config as imaged,  the unit posts, grub beeps, after about 30secs or so of black screen,  the cycling begins, red, green, blue, black repeat.  I did create a section in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf.  I don't remember the specifics, (its at work) I got a boot screen of 640x480 not usable.  So, I am going to try and modify this file to see if I can get some debug info. tx for your help.

Comment: I do not think I have had to edit xorg.conf file for 10 years. I used to have nVidia and did have to use nomodeset to boot & first install. But now there is Safe Boot & install restricted drivers that will include nVidia. Both Intel which I now use & AMD normally just work. But some hardware needs other settings and boot stops. Grub tries to use default graphical mode, but you can set it also. Not sure how with installer.

Comment: I haved added an Xorg.0.log dump of an unmodiefied freshly imaged unit.

Comment: Do not know xorg anymore. Someone else needs to chip in with further suggestions.

Comment: Can I get a Bump?

Comment: I've added a link.

Comment: Anybody?  Bumpity Bump?

Comment: If Intel 530. Some older comments: https://askubuntu.com/questions/698168/cant-get-intel-hd-graphics-530-skylake-i7-6700-to-work But HP site says other video versions, they must use same model for different configurations. and some show 1600x900 and others 1920 x 1080, so specific model important.

Comment: Hi again @oldfred,  well that threat is 5years old or so.  Some if not all of these issues should be resolved.  Unless there has been a regression.  Otherwise,  I don't know where to look to find a clue as to why x server terminates.